# How to merge dataset in Python based on column value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe structured as follows:

```
"Location","filePath","startLine","endLine","startColumn","endColumn","codeElementType","description", "codeElement","repository","sha1","url","type","description.1"
```

An example of the dataframe is the following:

[image]

I need to merge the entry that has the same sha1.

An example of output shoud be the following:
Supposing that this is the input:
[image]

The expected output should be the following:
[image]
This bacause the in this case, the first two lines has the same sha1.

I try the following snippet:

```
agg_functions=["Location","filePath","startLine","endLine", "startColumn","endColumn","codeElementType","description",
               "codeElement","repository","sha1","url","type","description.1"]
df_new = df.groupby(df['sha1']).aggregate(agg_functions)
print(df_new)
```

However, is always thrown the following expection:

```
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Location'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

agg_functions should be references to functions, not column names.

for example:

```py
agg_functions = [np.sum, "mean"]
```

see [DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)

I can't help with an exact fix. I must confess the text in the images you posted is too small for me to understand what your final result needs to be.